# Why do I not need to use htmlEntities?

Tags: php, mysql, html, zend-framework, utf-8

I'm pulling data from my database that is as such (raw):

```
long's streetWe’d " tree < < ! cool & <body>
```

From everything I understand, for this to be output to a html page i should need to wrap it in htmlEntities.

But when I wrap it, it outputs nothing.
var_dump shows:

```
long's streetWe&acirc;��d &quot; tree &lt; &lt; ! cool &amp; &lt;body&gt;
```

Wrapping in htmlspecialchars outputs:

```
long's streetWe’d &quot; tree &lt; &lt; ! cool &amp; &lt;body&gt;
```

var_dump output is the same for this one.

**BUT** outputting without using a wrapping function outputs it exactly as I want it to appear, as it is stored on the database.

When I output it it's being displayed via a forms populate method (this value is in a larger array of data)

I have no clue why it does this. Does anyone have any idea?

This is all built in php using zend with a mysql db.

Kind Regards,

Comment: You are displaying this on a web page via HTML?

Comment: Yes, its being populated into a form and the form is being output to the html page

Comment: Post the code you are using to output this text.

Comment: Are you sure your RAW string reaaly as you posted here? Maybe it's already encoded in DB? Have you tried accessing it via mysql console interface (not phpMyAdmin)?

Comment: In my experience `htmlentities()` is usually a horrible hack to make up for incorrect encoding somewhere along the line and causes more problems than it solves - if the database, the database connector and the output document all use the same character set (utf-8 for instance) you should _probably_ not need to use `htmlentities()`. `htmlspecialchars()` **yes** - `htmlentities()` not so much (there are specific cases for it, but generally, no).

Comment: @CD001, escaping output is also used to prevent cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: the data is 100% raw but interestingly mysql commandline shows: long's streetWed " tree < < ! cool & <body>

Comment: @MarcusAdams : ye-es, but in the case of HTML, `htmlentities()` is **not** the right way to go about it; if you want to sanitise it, use a parser like HTML Purifier or something. I only **ever** seem to see people using `htmlentities()` when attempting to fix character encoding errors.

Comment: So, it feels strange but all I am doing to my data is filtering/validating it upon user input (using prepared statements) and then simply outputting the data.. as I don't need to sanitize as it already displays correctly - if its going into a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the forms populate method expects you to give it text and not HTML, so it converts to HTML before outputting the data.

This is a standard, and sensible approach to the problem. Data should be escaped at the last possible moment (to avoid it being escaped inappropriately).

Comment: When I echo the content that I am populating the form with I still get the correct values output without using any functions. BUT if i echo it with htmlspecialchars I also get the correct output, but htmlentities still outputs: long's streetWeâ��d " tree < < ! cool & <body>.  So i think what was said about the form was correct.. it auto formats the text - but how is the echo using no functions (not in the form) outputting the correct data.